# Is the a direct or indirect way to create terraform code from resources, that were created with the management console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Creating resources in the management console is generally easier. I would like to create resources there first and then turn it into terraform code. Is this possible somehow, EDIT: by not letting other software scan your account?

After that, i would like to adapt the terraform code and create the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most popular way is through [former2](https://github.com/iann0036/former2):

> Generate CloudFormation / Terraform / Troposphere templates from your existing AWS resources

Comment: Okay, but this scans my aws account with a program, i do not think, that i want that. Is there another option?

Comment: @David There is no other option, unless you want to manually create the code yourself.

Comment: Cant you use cloudtrail and check the commands and map them to terraform. Can you import the state and reuse it? Aren't these options?